# Can I use a digital signature in this scenario? With c#

Tags: c#, digital-signature, public-key-encryption

I want to sign an xml document using a private key. And then when my client receives the software for them to be able to verify that the xml document hasnt changed by using a public key.

I want to distribut the same public key amongst all of my customers so that we can issue licenses to them.

Is this possible? I am using c# and .net.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is perfectly possible. Here is a comprehensive overview: [How to: Verify the Digital Signatures of XML Documents with .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229950.aspx)

Also here is how to sign documents for later verification: [In C#, sign an xml with a x.509 certificate and check the signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195728/in-c-sign-an-xml-with-a-x-509-certificate-and-check-the-signature)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.  There are more important questions when putting together a solution.

- Do you want this verification to be done automatically by your program?
- Do you want to set up your own public key infrastructure?
- Does your company already have a public signing certificate?

Depending on the answers, you might not need to write any code.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a nice article here about licenses using XML digital signatures: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/xmldsiglic.aspx