# How to verify an X509Certificate2 against an X509Certificate2Collection chain

Tags: .net, single-sign-on, x509certificate, pkcs#7, saml-2.0

I'm writing a SAML 2.0 response parser to handle POST authentication in ASP.Net (in C# and MVC, but that's less relevant).

So I have a `.p7b` file to validate with and that can be read into a `X509Certificate2Collection` and a sample assertion - a base 64 encoded SAML response.

Ideally I want to use the built in `WSSecurityTokenSerializer`, but [that fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108564), so I'm looking for a way that works.

I'm reading the XML directly instead:

```
// get the base 64 encoded SAML
string samlAssertionRaw = GetFromHttpRequest();

// load a new XML document
var assertion = new XmlDocument { PreserveWhitespace = true };
assertion.LoadXml(samlAssertionRaw);

// use a namespace manager to avoid the worst of xpaths
var ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(assertion.NameTable);
ns.AddNamespace("samlp", @"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol");
ns.AddNamespace("saml", @"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion");
ns.AddNamespace("ds", SignedXml.XmlDsigNamespaceUrl);

// get the signature XML node
var signNode = assertion.SelectSingleNode(
    "/samlp:Response/saml:Assertion/ds:Signature", ns);

// load the XML signature
var signedXml = new SignedXml(assertion.DocumentElement);
signedXml.LoadXml(signNode as XmlElement);

// get the certificate, basically:
// signedXml.KeyInfo.OfType<KeyInfoX509Data>().First().
//     Certificates.OfType<X509Certificate2>().First()
// but with added checks
var certificate = GetFirstX509Certificate(signedXml);

// check the key and signature match
if (!signedXml.CheckSignature(certificate, true))
{
    throw new SecurityException("Signature check failed.");
}

// go on and read the SAML attributes from the XML doc
```

That lot works, but all it's doing is checking that the signature and the `X509Certificate2` public key in the SAML response match. It doesn't in any way verify who it's from, and I need to do that before accepting the SAML authentication.

There appear to be two ways to check the certificate found in the SAML response - I can do `certificate.Verify()` or I can do the check with the signature `signedXml.CheckSignature(certificate, false)`.

However both return false.

I think this is because they're being checked against the machine store or possibly online (I'm not sure how to check). I want to check them against the `X509Certificate2Collection` retrieved from the `.p7b` file instead - the certificates registered on the machine should be ignored and just the `.p7b` certificates checked.

There doesn't appear to be any way to pass the `X509Certificate2Collection` to either the `Verify` or `CheckSignature` methods.

Is this the right check to be doing on the SAML response?

Is there any way to use the `.p7b` certificates the way I want to?

Comment: What does GetFirstX509Certificate do?

Comment: I asked a similar question here: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3905/verify-saml-response-is-from-a-trusted-source but ultimately ended up at your post because I'm having the same problem with CheckSignature

Comment: @theycallmemorty - I try to explain in the comments, but it does `signedXml.KeyInfo[0].Certificates[0] as X509Certificate2`, but with checks and casts.

Comment: I found this and thought you might find it helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195728/in-c-sign-an-xml-with-a-x-509-certificate-and-check-the-signature

Comment: @theycallmemorty - cheers, but that's kind of a different problem: they're having problems signing, while I can check the signature and public key match, but can't verify the public key is from a trusted provider.

Comment: Have you toyed with the [X509Chain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509chain.aspx) to get better information on what part of the verification is failing?

Comment: @Smudge202 - yes, it considers one of the certificates in my `X509Certificate2Collection` (sourced from my `.p7b`) file to not be valid. This is a development environment and they're self-issued certificates - I don't need to know whether the `.p7b` certificates are globally valid, I need to know SAML sender's certificate is valid for just that collection. Maybe if I could reset the `X509Chain` somehow to not check the source store?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried using a custom `X509Chain` configured to search an [`ExtraStore`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509chainpolicy.extrastore.aspx) of certificates during the validation process. Something like the following:

```
// Placeholder for the certificate to validate
var targetCertificate = new X509Certificate2();
// Placeholder for the extra collection of certificates to be used
var certificates = new X509Certificate2Collection();

var chain = new X509Chain();

chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;
chain.ChainPolicy.ExtraStore.AddRange(certificates);

bool isValidCertificate = chain.Build(targetCertificate);
```

In the example the revocation check is also disabled but if you have online or offline access to the CRL you could enable it.

---

The `ExtraStore` should allow to include intermediate certificates that are not in the machine/user store. However, the trusted root certificate may need to be in the machine or user store depending on the one specified in `X509Chain` because otherwise you'll get an `UntrustedRoot` fail. If not even the root can be available in a machine or user store you could try to walk up the resulting chain and guarantee that the only error you have is due to an untrusted root and at the same time guaranteeing that the chain root is what you would expect based on the `X509Certificate2Collection` you have for validation.

Alternatively you could create your own custom [`X509CertificateValidator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.selectors.x509certificatevalidator.aspx) to validate a certificate taking only in consideration a provided `X509Certificate2Collection`.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that - `chain.Build` comes back as invalid because my `X509Certificate2Collection` is invalid. However I'm not looking to validate the collection, and I'm happy to take the contents of the `.p7b` as authoritative - I just want to check the SAML certificate against the `.p7b` collection.

Comment: I think the problem might be related to `chain.ChainPolicy.ExtraStore.AddRange` - I'm not looking to add to the existing machine or user store, I need to start fresh with just the keys in the `.p7b` file.

Comment: What's the `ChainStatus` you get after you perform the build? It was my understanding that the `ExtraStore` would not add nothing to teh machine or user stores and just include the specified certificates in the validation process.

Comment: The certificates in my `.p7b` file are test environment ones - they don't come from a valid authority. I don't want to check them though, I want to check the SAML certificate against them.

Comment: Ok, I can get your code to work if I add `chain.ChainPolicy.VerificationFlags = X509VerificationFlags.AllFlags;`, which I think means that it's not checking the collection it has but it's still checking the certificate it's been passed. Is this right? Any ideas what the consequences of not verifying the chain will be?

Comment: From the docs the `AllFlags` will skip every verification step associated with each of the others verification flags that are defined. In that conditions I'm not sure what exactly is checked, but have you tried a smaller combination of flags. You said that the certificates don't come from a valid CA, so the flag `AllowUnknownCertificateAuthority` is a good option. Try combining the least amount of flags while having a valid result and then check if you can live without the verification steps you skipped.